# Remove reference and change static variables within a method

Tags: java

Let's say we got an object and a static variable that counts the generated objects

```
variable = new Foo();
Foo.getObjCounter(); // -> 1
```

Is there a way in java to put this code:

```
variable = null;
Foo.decreaseFooCounter();
```

Into one method such as:

```
variable.delete();
Foo.getFooCounter(); // -> 0
```

or

```
Foo.delete(variable);
Foo.getFooCounter(); // -> 0
```

Comment: Override `delete`?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve such behaviour by using [`WeakReference`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) or more specific a `Set` backed by a `WeakHashMap`. See the following example:

```
class Foo {
    private static final Set<Foo> references = Collections.newSetFromMap(new WeakHashMap<>());

    public Foo() {
        references.add(this); // register ourselves
    }

    public static int getFooCounter() {
        return references.size();
    }

    // rest of the methods
}
```

Though the reference to the created `Foo` will only be removed if they have been free'd up by the garbage collector. To quote the doc:

> *[...] Suppose that the garbage collector determines at a certain point in time that an object is weakly reachable. At that time it will atomically clear **all weak references** to that object [...]*

Comment: So in a way this operates like [finalize()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize()) ?

Therefore, it also depends on the execution of the garbage collector, which happens rather randomly, meaning that perhaps at a point in time when the object no longer exists, the static counting variable has a wrong value?

Comment: @ManuelT exactly, generally there is no real reliable way to automatically deregister the instance from the `references` field I've used in my example. But the way I've shown should work for most of the time